# Why did God "divide the light from the darkness"? Gen 1:4

Tags: creation

Because prior to the introduction of light, "darkness was upon the face of the deep," one would assume that darkness was created before light.

I assume it *was* created because nothing supersedes God, Who created the world from nothing, whereas darkness is most certainly NOT nothing. In order for there to be darkness as we know it, space absolutely has to exist, and it would be wrong to assume that darkness is a "natural" characteristic of space, since nothing is "natural" unless and until God says it is.

Physical darkness is the absence of the electromagnetic wave spectrum that the human eye (and any machinery we can conceivably invent) can detect.

Spiritual darkness is the inability of one's heart and/or soul to detect spiritual light.
So far so good.

However, separating one from the other means - or does it? - that the two (light and darkness) overlapped, or were somehow merged together, before God divided them.

(Note also that He does not TELL them to go their separate ways; He divides them Himself, directly. Manually, so to speak).

What did the Universe in which light and darkness were mixed together look like? Why did God find it necessary (or did He?) to separate one from the other?

> Gen 1:4 - And God saw that the light was good, and He **separated** the
> light from the darkness.

Comment: Since you are messing in the electromagnetic waves - how about the "recombination era" - the moment when the Universe becomes transparent (i.e. it is possible to see through)? Before that, there is neither light nor darkness. Then, the darknes emerges and it becomes possible to see whatever the first light sources were (quazars and later stars).

Comment: I'd shy away from appeals to physics to answer a question like this because God created the physical laws, and apparently from the creation account didn't actually put them in place until *after he had begun creating*. So for example, the earth is created before the sun, moon, and stars; light is created before that which gives light; day and night happen before there is a sun, etc. God made the physical laws; He isn't subject to them. Anyway hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

> 1 John 1:5-7ESV
> This is the message we have heard from him and proclaim to you, that God is light, and in him is no darkness at all. If we say we have fellowship with him while we walk in darkness, we lie and do not practice the truth. But if we walk in the light, as he is in the light, we have fellowship with one another, and the blood of Jesus his Son cleanses us from all sin.

I have been taught that you can not add darkness but only light. You can take light away and darkness is the result. Darkness is the absence of light. Matthew 8:12
For God to have created darkness would mean that God created a place separated from himself. In the end of the Bible we see a return to what once was.

> Revelation 21:22-27 ESV
> And I saw no temple in the city, for its temple is the Lord God the Almighty and the Lamb. And the city has no need of sun or moon to shine on it, for the glory of God gives it light, and its lamp is the Lamb. By its light will the nations walk, and the kings of the earth will bring their glory into it, and its gates will never be shut by day—and there will be no night there. They will bring into it the glory and the honor of the nations. But nothing unclean will ever enter it, nor anyone who does what is detestable or false, but only those who are written in the Lamb's book of life.

Similar to this is, God is good. Mark 10:18
When one asks the question “Where does evil come from?”. One inversely is asking “Where does good come from?”.

Why did God “divide the light from the darkness”?
-It is to bring glory to himself.-

> Proverbs 25:2 ESV
> It is the glory of God to conceal things,
> but the glory of kings is to search things out.

> Jeremiah 13:16 ESV
> Give glory to the LORD your God
> before he brings darkness,
> before your feet stumble
> on the twilight mountains,
> and while you look for light
> he turns it into gloom
> and makes it deep darkness.

> 2 Corinthians 4:6 ESV
> For God, who said, “Let light shine out of darkness,” has shone in our hearts to give the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ.

Comment: Great post! +1 *God created a place separated from himself* Or, we know where evil originated, so really evil *separated itself* from God, thereby creating darkness. which permeated the entire cosmos.

Comment: Hi Mr.Dave, welcome to the site. This is a great first post, upvoted +1. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), and thanks for contributing!

Comment: This aligns well with Islamic theology. In Islam, we believe things are granted. Just as how darkness is inherit, we as humans are plain/weak in essence. Then we are **granted** wisdom, power, freedom. But our essence is being weak as wisdom, power can easily be taken from us, and then we go back to being nothing but a attribute-less entity. Other than inherently being weak, we're an everless entity when it comes to accepting/refusing anything granted to us i.e. we're given wisdom/power whether or not we want it...

Answer (score 3):

Existential consequences: It is about the **conception** of the 'day' for work and the 'night' for sleep which in turn determines optimal design of the solar system including the Earth's rotation and diameter.

Comment: If the Earth does not spin on its axis there is no 'alternation' of night and day. Some live in darkness and some in light and some in a mixture!

Comment: The explanatory verse immediately follows: Gen 1:5 God called the light “day,” and the darkness He called “night.” Just wondering where this spiritual stuff come from!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. In the beginning God created the heavens (plural) and the earth.
2. The earth was inglorious (*bohu*) and markedly so (*tohu*).
3. Darkness was upon the face of the deep.
4. The Spirit of God hovered ('fluttered') upon the face of the waters.

After creation there was a marked ingloriousness to earth and there was a depth (in creation itself) which, due to darkness on its face, was obscure as to what it contained.

The Spirit of God did not rest in this condition nor alight upon this condition but was active, close to it, separate from it, in activity regarding it.

A condition ... and a concern.

Later, the reason was revealed - the presence of a spirit which was serpentine, adversarial, deceitful, cruel, murderous and utterly self-centred.

The problem - the dark depth, the condition, and the adverse presence - was in the heavens.

Not the visible heavens, for as yet there were none, stars yet unformed.

The problem was in the second heavens (not the third where God dwells and his his throne but) that which is of creation but is not visible substance : powers, energies, principalities, authorities in structured layers and in conjunctions of operation which composite structure is necessary for space and energy and matter to exist.

Into this scenario, came light.

And that Light was not of the darkness. It was a further creation. Creation has a certain liability to it, because of what intelligent creatures will do (they will always do) and the consequences of that wilful action.

So God divided the Light (a new creation) from that of the already created.

It is distinct, it is separate and it has purpose.

All of this is spiritual.

It is a New Creation.

Comment: Very good, thanks.

Comment: @Ricky Thank you. Your question up-voted +1. Good question.

Comment: Aye a good duplicate question.Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of God creating darkness because darkness is the mere absence of light.  It was necessary for God to define visible light from the rest of the electromagnetic spectrum before creating the sun, earth's atmosphere, plant, and animals because visible light is a integral part of how they function.  The basis for the question is what does בדל mean.  The use of this verb in the Old Testament is Hiphil thus the idea of causing.

**Figure 1**.  Senses of בדל in the Old Testament.
[image]

First, look at this from God's perspective:

> גַּם־חֹשֶׁךְ֮ לֹֽא־יַחְשִׁ֪יךְ מִ֫מֶּ֥ךָ וְ֭לַיְלָה כַּיֹּ֣ום יָאִ֑יר ‬כַּ֝חֲשֵׁיכָ֗ה כָּאֹורָֽה‬׃
> (Psalm 139:12, BHS)

```
   even the darkness is not dark to you; 
  the night is bright as the day, 
  for darkness is as light with you.
                (Psalm 139:12, ESV)
```

Light is a narrow part of the electromagnetic spectrum.  From God's standpoint of vision there is nothing to initially distinguish it from other electromagnetic waves.  As a first step in creation, especially related to the Earth and its solar system, God defined the narrow spectrum called light.  Our sun, the atmosphere, plants, and the eyes of animals are all created with the significance of this narrow electromagnetic spectrum God called light.  The sense you can say God created darkness is, unlike God, who can always see, people can only see when light is present.  Without light is dark for people.

[image]

Comment: You have posted this before on the duplicate question. Do you not think that is unfair ?

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/680/in-genesis-14-what-does-it-mean-when-god-separated-light-from-darkness?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Bagpipes  Actually a posted that answer after posting this one., after noticing that it also answered that question.  The postings were only a few minutes apart.

Comment: Oh sorry perry, i did not realize that. So you do not think it is a duplicate? or do you think it is not a duplicate?

Comment: While my answer is a duplicate, technically the question is not. That is, a duplicate depends on how the two questions are answered.

Comment: I just posted a comment on the [other Answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/75789/27581). These need to be tailored to the Answer so they don't address both. We don't post [boilerplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_text) here on SE, certainly not overtly. I like these though and don't want to have to delete any. Please, please edit and tailor them to their respective Questions. You can keep the images in both, and you may even link to each other. Be special, give people a reason to read both Answers, please.

Comment: I hope the expanded introduction is enough here.  If not, I need more time.  My mother died this week,

Comment: I deleted the other answer until I get more time.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the creation account in Genesis involves the three key concepts listed in Gen 1:2

> Now the earth was (1) formless/chaotic and (2) void/empty, and (3) darkness was over the surface
> of the deep. And the Spirit of God was hovering over the surface of
> the waters.

Note the three significant words here:

1. תֹּהוּ (tohu) = formlessness, chaotic
2. בֹּהוּ (bohu) = emptiness
3. חשֶׁךְ (choshek) = darkness

See also Jer 4:23. The the succeeding account of creation of our world, God sets about giving it form/shape, filling it and banishing darkness.

Thus, God's first act is separate light from darkness by providing light.

[Note: I do not thing God actually created light at this moment because light has always been integral to God's existence as per 1 John 1:5.]

The six days of creation naturally fall into two sets of three:

**Days 1-3 - Separation/forming**

- day 1: God separates light from darkness and thus creates day/night
- day 2: God separates waters above from the waters below and thus creates the "heavens"
- day 3: God separates dry land ("earth") from seas and creates vegetation

**Days 4-6 - Population/filling**

- day 4: God places lights in the day and lights in the night
- day 5: God places birds in the heavens and creatures in the sea
- day 6: God places animals on the land and creates humans

Comment: Uh ... Here's what happens BEFORE the separation: "And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.  And God saw the light, that it was good." Thus, He provides light FIRST, and only THEN does he separate it from darkness. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ricky - that is obviously true. But that record does not explicitly say that God created light. My analysis above simply follows the pattern of the entire section.  Further, the primary function of allowing light to appear was to create the separation between night vs day.

Answer (score 0):

We must be careful to use the understanding that the physical and spiritual are connected - in type, in principle etc.

We know where sp. darkness came from. Before this, we can only assume that evil was not present in all creation. When Lucifer allowed pride to become sin, he *effectively* created sp. darkness - he initiated evil and this affected everything that was - drawing a third of the angels into his den of darkness, lies, deceit and hate.

When God created, or rather, *re-created* earth in the Gen account, He allowed, no effectively *placed* evil within it's confines. This was not necessary, but a recognition of the cosmos filling evil that worked against His principles of love.

He used this darkness to bring about a better creation. He separated or divided, spiritually speaking, the areas that He would maintain, and those that evil would reign for a time. This applied to some humans and other areas of creation that would remain His and for His purposes.

In Gen, light *could* shine upon the earth, but it was restricted from doing so. Darkness of itself is not evil - it is a natural phenomenon of a body passing in front of a light source.

The sp. analogy of separation applied to physical creation and in a grander sense all of creation which at it's very core is of a spiritual nature.

**What did the Universe in which light and darkness were mixed together look like?**

This is where the analogy of phy. to sp. breaks down.

With God, they are not mixed together - they (temporarily) co-exist in the same place. God never *mixes* with evil, there is no *shade* or grey areas with God. This is why it is so important to understand the differing will that Jesus had apart from God. In him, for a time, we had grey areas where darkness was able to influence the holy son of God. But that is not part of this Q.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a very crucial point is missing in the entire discussion: in all Gen 1 cases **the verb ‘badal’ (to separate) is a Hifil form** (not Qal) which is the **causative** form. That is something that causes the separation. If we read Gen 1:14 carefully, we see it is a source of light (i.e. maor מָאוֹר e.g. Sun) that is causing the separation. Besides, the same source of light causes the alternation of the seasons too.

Now that we know how the solar system works, we can understand that the **rotation** and the **revolution** of the earth are the causes of the alternation of day and night and the alternation of seasons respectively.

Gen 1:14 (NASB)

> And God said, “Let there be lights in the dome of the sky to separate
> the day from the night; and let them be for signs and for seasons and
> for days and years,

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the creation narrative. The separation of light from darkness happens on day 1, whereas the creation of the sun, moon, and stars to separate day from night (not quite the same thing) happens on day 4.

Comment: If we read Gen 1:4-5 together, it is not that difficult to assume what might be the purpose of the separation. In Gen 1:14 the entire solar system is integrated such that the light sources are observable from the earth.

Comment: In other words, the conception of day and night in Gen 1:4-5 is being actualized in Gen 1:14.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know because the Bible doesn't tell us. We can speculate, but I'm not sure it's helpful to do so. I'd chalk this up to one of the many mysteries of Scripture.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! So, so interesting. New here. Didn't know this discussion existed.

One thing I have learned from the bible is that God authored His word for everybody. A simple message that is easy to understand. Gen 1:1, he created the heavens and the Earth. At this point the sun. moon stars and hence light existed.

The Earth was covered in a thick dense vapor (as science tells us, like Venus I can imagine). No light reached the watery surface of the Earth.

God began to thin out the vapors allowing light to reach the surface dependent on the rotation of the Earth.

This process continued until He separated the waters above from the waters below leaving an expanse in between. Since we have just experienced massive flooding where I live, I can vouch for the waters above.

In the fourth period of preparing the Earth for habitation, the separation was sufficient to see the luminaries from the surface of the Earth.

This chapter is written from the perspective of somebody on the surface of the Earth because prior to a relatively few years ago, any other perspective would have been inconceivable.

One last comment: The original poster referred to darkness as a thing. I'm not so sure. Something which, to me, is difficult to conceive is the fact that prior to the creation of the physical universe, there was nothing. What we think of as space is in fact nothing. If you remove everything (except you) from the universe, there is nothing, no direction, no velocity, no light and no end point. There are no physical rules, just emptiness. All that changed some 14 billion years ago when God created the universe. No wonder in Job 26:7, the Earth is described as hanging on nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: I need to think about what you said. However, let me point out something related to your last comment. If we wished to be all pedantic about it, we could say that "nothing" could mean "nothing that is detectible or even conceivable by human intellect. Which (the intellect) is limited by the aforementioned five senses and not, say, 14 or 100. God, since He's omnipotent, created the Universe along with all the rules, one of which is "darkness is the absence of light."

Comment: Thanks agarza - I may have stumbled into the wrong party. I had to Google hermeneutics to find out what it means.

Comment: @Ricky - Thanks for your comment. I wasn't sure if I'd be back but it was rude of me to leave your comment hanging. My answer referred to the physical universe. God created the heavens and the Earth. By implication, there was nothing (from our perspective) before that. We know that Jesus was the firstborn of all creation (Col 1:15), a  [master craftsman](https://biblehub.com/text/proverbs/8-30.htm) and all things were made through him (John 1:3). Clearly, prior to anything detectable being in the universe, there was already life, power and intelligence. Just nothing physical.